# Antivirus to protect multiple machines

Tags: home-networking

I have WiFi cable internet going through the modem onto a host laptop. If i put an antivirus onto that host computer is it enough to protect others using the WiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. While the anti-virus software on one computer might alert you to suspicious traffic coming from another machine, one machine will do nothing to scan the hard drives on the other machines on the network. If the infections on the other computers don't cause any suspicious traffic, you will see no alerts from that one machine with the antivirus software.